# Mysql rank rows and columns from max to min and show the rank in php code ?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to make a code that does the some things.

I have got a table with columns and rows and i need to take from the table all max from the table and rank them from high to low.

For example :

[image]

and to show it in php file like this :

`1- PS , 2- PD , 3- PS , 4- LSI , 5- PD , 6- PS , 7- FRD , 8- LSI , 9- PD , 10- PS , 11- AK , 12- FRD , 13- LSI , 14 PD , 15- PS etc ...`

Comment: We need more information: where is the table data located? Are you trying to read an HTML table and load its results into an array, which will be processed the way you described afterwards?

Comment: greater is who have the first element bigger , for example PD=4000 is the third positioned and LSI=4000 is the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
 Select cod,val
From
(
 Select 'pd' as cod, pd as val FROM Table1
union all
Select 'lsi' as cod, lsi as val FROM Table1
union all
Select 'val' as cod,frd as val FROM Table1
union all
Select 'ak' as cod,ak as val FROM Table1
union all
Select 'ps' as cod,ps as val FROM Table1
union all
Select 'pr' as cod, pr as val FROM Table1
) x
order by val desc
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d515/10)

then in php code just fetch it with ordering
example

```
    for($i=1 ; $i<= mysql_num_rows($query) ; $i++){  // or you can use count(*) in your query
    echo $i.'-'.$row['cod'] ;
    }
  //not tested but its this idea
```

Comment: thank you very much , this is the idea but i want another thing , how can i make the first values :

(1114, 12, 1, 444, 7, 444), to be apportioned with numbers 2/3/4/5/6 ... etc ? for example 12/2=6 and 6/3=2 ... and make the second row of value ? so , i put the first value for pd ,ps etc and those automatically apportioned

Comment: sorry i didnt understand what you want. can you edit your question and add your wished results or what you want and explain it good?

Comment: i was thinking to do mathematical operations for values in dtb

Comment: yes u can just explain , and show wished results in  your question

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select type, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank, amount
from (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
cross join
(select 'PD' type, PD amount from mytable union all
 select 'LSI' type, LSI from mytable union all
 select 'FRD' type, FRD from mytable union all
 select 'AK' type, AK from mytable union all
 select 'PS' type, PS from mytable union all
 select 'PR' type, PR from mytable) v
order by amount desc
```

Comment: the table is in mysql , table name "partite" , elements are PS , PS , LSI , FRD , AK , PR and the numbers are for each element diferent